# Simple multithreading program with emscripten

Tags: c, multithreading, emscripten

I am trying to create a simple program with thread support using Emscripten:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp) {
  printf("From Thread \n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t tid;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
    printf("Before join\n");
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I am executed it in Firefox and I compile using `-s USE_PTHREADS=1`.
This is the output I got in the console:

```
Before Thread
Preallocating 1 workers for a pthread spawn pool.
Before join
```

But I expected:

```
Before Thread
Preallocating 1 workers for a pthread spawn pool.
Before join
After Thread
```

It is like the thread is not ending. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is weird that `Middle` is printed when it never exists in your code...

Comment: This is the output I got after running the above code, `Before Thread
Before join
From Thread 
After Thread` Not what you mentioned in your code.

Comment: Your above code should print like 1. Before Thread 2. From Thread 3. Before join 4. After Thread. If it is printing like this it is working fine. But what is SDL.h? Before join and From Thread might print in different order that is also fine.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when pasting results from the console. I edited the question. So I got `Before Thread and Before join` but I don't get `After Thread`. @LethalProgrammer , I am using Emscripten, are you?

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` before `return 0` and it will automagically work.

Comment: @RingØ, no, it is not working. I am using Emscripten.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by compiling with `-s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=x` with x = number of thread created.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try it when I'll work on that project again. Actually I gave up using thread as it slows my program VERY much. Do you have the same behavior? Maybe using PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE resolve the issue?

Comment: I can't tell you as I didn't measure anything. I was just trying to see how emscripten handles multi-threaded code.